# Best way to cut + merge paths in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

So, I've been making geometric text using a grid and circles to form letters, but I was wonsering what the best way to actually cut and merge the paths to form the letters. For example, this 's' letter:

[image]

So what would be the best way to end up with the above result?
I've been using the shape builder tool (Shift+M) but sometimes it won't work and other times it will.
[image]

I know this isn't the best way to achieve what I am trying to achieve, so what is the best way?
I'm looking for a geometrically *perfect* shape, so, not using the pen tool.
Any advice on the best and most efficient method would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try doubleclicking on the tool and adjust the options.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a pretty straightforward geometric pattern, the simplest approach may be to use the **Direct Selection Tool** <kbd>A</kbd> and select the individual anchor points and/or line segments you want to eliminate:

[image]

[image]

[image]

To clean things up after deleting undesired portions of the shape, use the same **Direct Selection Tool** <kbd>A</kbd> to select two anchor points you want to join and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to connect those two points to create one cohesive shape or, in this case, a letterform.

[image]

[image]

***Note:*** This is a similar approach to using the Shape Builder Tool but it will give you a little more control and precision.

Answer (score -1):

use the pathfinder tool. much easier and simpler to use.

Comment: Except that pathfinder will not work in this case.